# 100% Width Creating Horizontal Scroll Bar

Tags: width, overflow, horizontal-scrolling

I'm creating a fluid website where the width is set to 100%. Everything works fine, but I've noticed when I shrink the browser width to around 751px, a horizontal scroll appears. Problem is, I've set the min-width to 737px.  I don't have any padding on the container div, and the margins are set to auto. Could it be that the vertical scroll bar's width is causing this?

My demo site is located at http://stevepolitodesign.comlu.com/

Answer (score 0):

Scrollbar appears at 737px for me, what browser are you using? I was using Safari (latest, ML)

Nice website, by the way!

Comment: Thanks! I'm thinking it's my OS, because it appears in Safari, Chrome and Firefox. I'm running Lion 10.7.3

Comment: 373 in Chrome, too. ML = Mountain Lion, by the way. I don't see why the behaviour would have changed.

Comment: Oh haha, didn't realize I had ML. Well, at least it's working for everyone else!